# Why does $\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \frac{\cos(\lambda x) - \cos(\lambda y)}{\lambda} = 0$

Tags: calculus

Why does $$\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \frac{\cos(\lambda x) - \cos(\lambda y)}{\lambda} = 0$$

Or I should really rephrase my question. Is this limit *obvious*?

Motivation comes from $$\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \int_{a}^{b} \sin(\lambda t) dt$$

The book I have simply states that limit is $0$. I worked it out and I found that

$$\left | \frac{\cos(\lambda x) - \cos(\lambda y)}{\lambda} \right | \leq |x - y|$$

I am unable to see how the RHS goes to $0$

Comment: The top stays little.

Comment: @Potato An argument using power series would need more discussion since those are local identities while here we consider $\lambda\to\infty$. The method given is fairly mechanical too, not?

Comment: @Potato, ah yes! that is indeed a even more obvious insight. +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT:

As for real $z,-1\le\cos z\le 1\implies -2\le\cos \lambda x-\cos \lambda y\le 2$

So, $$-\frac2{\lambda}\le\frac{\cos \lambda x-\cos \lambda y}{\lambda}
\le\frac2{\lambda}$$

Use [Squeeze Theorem](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Squeeze_Theorem)

Comment: Ah okay; 15char

Comment: +1 Viva lab, Viva India.